# ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'general' when trying to add a repository

Tags: linux-mint, apt, python, ppa

When I try to `sudo add-apt-repository <any>`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1387, in <module>
    codename = config_parser.get("general", "base_codename")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 330, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'general'
```

How can I fix this?

Could it have been caused by my switching `python` to `python3`?
(Now `python --version` is `Python 3.5.1` and `python2 --version` is `Python 2.7.6`)

Comment: Try installing `mintsystem` which seems to solve many similar cases.

Comment: `apt-get install` says _mintsystem is already the newest version_;

Tried `--reinstall` then, which reinstalled successfully (except for "_update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match mintsystem Default-Stop values (none)_"),
and then restarted, but I still get the same error

Comment: I ended up setting `python` back to `python2` instead of `python3`, and everything has been ok since then :/ I might have also reinstalled `pyenv`. So I'm not sure what *exactly* caused this nor what *exactly* fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

check your lsb-release file. did you change lsb-release contents? its located on /etc/lsb-release

change content of lsb-release to match your release. something like this:

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sarah
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18 sarah"
```

Comment: Never touched it, seems accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Until a better answer comes along, here is the copy of my comment about how I got around this in the end.

---

I ended up setting `python` back to `python2` instead of `python3`, and everything has been ok since then :/ I might have also reinstalled `pyenv`. So I'm not sure what *exactly* caused this nor what *exactly* fixed it.